# create correct procedure

Tags: plsql

I'm trying to write a simple PL/SQL procedure, but I keep getting errors I don't understand. there are some 
syntax failures, and I would appreciate if someone could help me with them.
I need to create a procedure that will allow me insert in a table particular person(varchar2) with two dates(DATE), his contract duration.
However his contract CAN'T be between existing dates, thus can't overlap, same person can have number of contacts but only between completely different periods.
I understand that I need to use INTERSECT, it's just I'm confused how to use it here, since I we have only one table. I've intersection before with two tables, how do I intersect it here? I;m also not sure if I can have 2 if statements
Thank you!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test1
(name             VARCHAR2,
 startDate        DATE,
 endDate          DATE) 
AS
overlap       NUMBER := 0;
CURSOR cursor IS 
SELECT date_from, date_to FROM contractTable;
BEGIN
   FOR row IN cursor LOOP
   /*check if there is an overlap between dates*/
     IF (startDate, endDate) INTERESECT (SELECT date_from, date_to FROM ContractTable) THEN
  overlap := overlap + 1;       
  END IF;
  /*if there isn't, then insert new contact for this person*/
  IF overlap <= 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO ContractTable VALUES(name, startDate, endDate);
  END IF;
  END test1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test1 (l_name IN VARCHAR2, l_start_date IN DATE, l_end_date IN DATE) 
IS 

    l_overlap_check NUMBER;

BEGIN

    SELECT count(*) INTO l_overlap_check
      FROM contract 
     WHERE (l_start_date between start_date and end_date 
           OR
            l_end_date between start_date and end_date)
      AND l_name = name;

    IF l_overlap_check = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO contract (name, start_date, end_date)
                      VALUES (l_name, l_start, l_end);
   END IF;

END;
```

I don't have an Oracle environment handy but that should be what you need.

Comment: I would include an exception handler to the procedure as a 'best practice'.